# Cant use Automapper 9 static API

Tags: c#, automapper

I cant use automapper static api in **Automapper 9**.

According to automapper documentation by Starting version 9.0, the static API is no longer available.

Is it a good idea to create a static version for my own or is it better to use dependency injection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to instiaialize an instance of the mapper and somehow access this way. This can be DI, it can be as simple as a static property somewhere where you put the mapper in.

OBVIOUSLY this means the mapper works correctly then - it always was ready for that, all the static api did provide was basically a "known location" that was defined in Automapper.

Comment: Thanks for your help, why Automapper force consumers to use  DI, Do we write mock tests for Mappers!?

Comment: Learn basics. Automapper does NOT force you to use DI - I basically have a MappingContainer static class that initializes automapper in the consturctor and exposes a static property. No DI involved. Just because there is no static API does not "force" you do use DI. And I do NOT write mock tests for mappers - I acutally do full integratio ntests down to the database. Many of my mappers are actually used in projections only.

Comment: @ShervinIvari AM aside, perhaps research a little _why_ using DI is preferred to global variables. This is just a clean coding general practice.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu That's right, but in some complicate solutions the utilities that you need is a lot, So you end with fat constractors.

Comment: There are ways around that, check MediatR for example, but going back to statics is not the answer. That's progress, trading one set of problems for another, hopefully smaller problems :)

Comment: I was not proposing to use statics. I was saying that (a) this is one of the altneratives and (b) nothign FORCES you to use DI. I implemented static as a fast workaround because it replaced one system with another. Also the DI in ASPNETCORE is an antipattern - you end up possibly modifying hundreds of controllers if you need one more DI in a base class. Ridiculous.